# awk print to file is appending not overwriting

Tags: linux, file, awk

i have an awk script that i need to write the output of a command to a file.  and it *should* be overwriting the value in the file so there is **only** one value.  but it is appending, giving me 1000 readings instead of just 1.  i am stumped.

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  getline < COMMAND
  MIN2 = $1
  close(COMMAND)

  print MIN2 > "lastValue.txt"
}
```

to be clear: the script otherwise works perfectly.  i just need it to OVERWRITE, NOT APPEND.  and to my eyes, that's what the `>` does.  if i had `>>` i would expect it to append, so i'm lost as to why the `>` is doing what `>>` should do.

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] which includes a minimal, complete awk script that's JUST enough to reproduce your problem plus sample input and expected output so it's easiest for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of the semantics of `>` in shell, awk is not shell and so, among other things, `>` doesn't mean the same in awk as it does in shell.

An awk script like:

```
for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    print i > "file"
}
```

is not the same semantics as a shell script like:

**a)**

```
for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ )); do
    echo "$i" > file
done
```

where the shell [re-]opens the output file in every loop iteration, it's the same as a shell script like this:

**b)**

```
for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ )); do
    echo "$i"
done > file
```

where the shell only opens the output file once, when the loop starts.

If you want an awk script to do what shell script "a)" above does, it'd be:

```
for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    print i > "file"
    close("file")
}
```

which for your code would be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  getline < COMMAND
  MIN2 = $1
  close(COMMAND)

  print MIN2 > "lastValue.txt"
  close("lastValue.txt")
}
```

but I can't come up with a reason why you'd want to write to a file 1000 times and then discard the first 999 lines instead of only writing to it once when you're done:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  getline < COMMAND
  MIN2 = $1
  close(COMMAND)
}
print MIN2 > "lastValue.txt"
```

Comment: the script you can't see is reading a digital input and writing last known value to the file.  the periodicity of the input is unknown AND random, so a fast cycle is required.  a python application reads the file every second for consumption in its program.  the python interpreter just can't read the input fast enough (≈15ms) *in conjunction with* the other things it's doing to catch the digital flip (26ms).  and, yeah, in hindsight, the `close("lastValue.txt")` seems obvious.  i had been thinking 'bash' instead of 'awk'.  thank you very much.  :)

Comment: i am open to something more efficient, btw.  the loop is simply for testing purposes. AND it would only be writing when the digital flip was captured, a theoretical max of 4/sec.  i just want to see how hard we can push it.

Comment: Post a new question if you'd like help with that,

Comment: lol.  you read my mind, Ed.  :)